# use public_html folder in laravel project to download a file

Tags: laravel, routes, download, cpanel, shared-hosting

I have a Laravel project in shared host and want to have a text file in *public_html* folder and access to it from address like `myproject.com/test.txt`

I try to create route for that but not work
I try edit *.htaccess* but no result! maybe i do it wrong

Comment: Docnot edit the `.htaccess`, you have to put the file inside the `public` folder, not `public_html`. Show us what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

Once the file is in the public folder, you can access it with `yoursite.com/test.txt` or using the `asset('test.txt')` helper., it's an asset that should be served just like your css files, static images..etc. and you don't to create a route for this.